# Problemas con proyecto java web al pasar de Tomcat 7 a Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Queria saber si me puedes ayudar con algo: Hace 2 dias migre una Java web aplication de Tomcat 7 a Tomcat 8.5. Pero ahora la aplicacion no corre bien y presenta errores extraños como por ejemplo que no encuentra un metodo de un archivo de JavaScript, algunas importanciones de librerias como Jquery o Bootstrap.

Estoy un poco desesperado por que es una app importante que estamos desarrollando y no sabemos si falta alguna configuradion en el Tomcat 8.5 para que esos errores deejen de salir.

PD: El error de el metodo "Iniciar Sesion()" en el archivo de JavaScript, lo solucionamos creando uno nuevo y poniendo solo ese metodo y ahi si lo identifico. Cabe mencionar que el archivo original donde estaba el metodo era extenso, como unas 2000 lineas de codigo. Los demas errores siguen persistiendo.

EDIT: Algunas capturas de errores

[image: Eror 1]

[image: Error 2]

[image: Este error lo arregle quitando unos ;]

Comment: Sin saber cómo se configura el Tomcat, cómo se despliegan los contextos y los recursos estáticos, el detalle de los errores... Es imposible saber qué puede pasar. [Edit] la pregunta y mejorarla puede hacer que las respondan más rápido

Comment: @Alfabravo Gracias por tu sugerencia. Editado.